# How to recover Google classic design from its new design?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I typed this into my address bar:

```
javascript:void(document.cookie=”PREF=ID=20b6e4c2f44943bb:U=4bf292d46faad806:TM=1249677602:LM=1257919388:S=odm0Ys-53ZueXfZG;path=/; domain=.google.com”);
```

However, I don't like the new design of Google. How to switch back? How to cancel this effect using Javascript? How to reverse by using Javascript?

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: This should probably be on superuser.com.

Comment: How to reverse it by using Javascript?

Comment: This is your third almost identical question in a few minutes. Please give your questions some thought...

Comment: @titaniumdecoy, things that don't belong on SO don't automatically belong on SU.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the cookies in this browser.

Comment: I want to do it by using javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Log out. Delete all your cookies. Problem should be solved.